# LINQ Query How to select Max value between start and end index

Tags: c#, linq

How do I use LINQ to query an array of numbers to get the highest value between start index and end index.

int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,8 ,7 ,6, 5 ,4 ,3 ,2 ,1};

I want to find the Max value between numbers[5] and numbers[8]

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to skip four elements, then take the max of the next four (#5..#8, inclusive):

```
var begin = 5;
var end = 8;
var res = numbers.Skip(begin-1).Take(end-begin+1).Max();
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
numbers.Skip( 5 ).Take( 4 ).Max();
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this: ?

```
numbers.Where((n, i) => i >= 5 && i <= 8).Max();
```