# LINQ Query How to select Max value between start and end index and the index of the max value

Tags: c#, linq

`int[] num = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};`

How do I use LINQ to get the Max value and the index of the Max value between index 3 and index 8?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661097/linq-query-how-to-select-max-value-between-start-and-end-index

Comment: No, that question is just to get the max, I am also looking to get the index of the max value in the array

Comment: this question contains nearly the same text as your other question. The philosophy here is to *try it yourself*, post an *example* of what you tried and what internet research you came up with, and then describe your problem in detail. I don't see any research effort.

Comment: There can be multiple indices if there are duplicate max elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var info = num.Select( (i, ind) => new {Value=i, Index=ind}).Skip(3).Take(6)
              .OrderByDescending(p => p.Value).First();

Console.WriteLine("Value {0} at Index {1}", info.Value, info.Index);
```

You could also use `Aggregate`:

```
var info = num.Select( (i, ind) => new {Value=i, Index=ind}).Skip(3).Take(6)
              .Aggregate((a, b) => b.Value > a.Value ? b : a);
```

This can be simplified if you use [MoreLinq's MaxBy()](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) or a similar routine to something a bit nicer:

```
var info = num.Select( (i, ind) => {Value=i, Index=ind}).Skip(3).Take(6)
              .MaxBy(p => p.Value);
```

Comment: Better than `.OrderByDescending(...).First()`, you could use `.Aggregate((a,p) => (a.Value > p.Value) ? a : p)`.  [Aggregate is specifically for these types of scenarios.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It's not a single query but may help.

```
var max = num.Skip(3).Take(4).Max(); 
var indexOfItem = num.Skip(3).Take(4).First(t => t.Equals(max)); // this is not correct, returns the value not the index.
```

Comment: Two things: Should take >4 (6 for 8 inclusive) if you want to get the proper number of elements.  Second, `First` is going to return the item, not the index of the item... The above code would return 9,9, not 9,8 (with Take(6)).